# Why I can execute files without execution permission if I use ld-2.31.so?

Tags: linux, permissions, shared-libraries, file-permissions, glibc

I am a bit shocked about this discover.
If I don't have execution permission on a file, say, foo... I can still execute it with:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./foo
```

(`ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is a symlink to `ld-2.31.so`).

Since I don't think I know what's really happening in that command, since I don't really know what `ld-2.31.so` is, can you explain why can that execute files? Is this what happens in background that we don't see, when we just do `./foo` ? What is ld-2.31.so ? What's its role? Are there any other "tricks" and libraries(I don't know their purpose, I am a newbie actually) that do similar jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this what happens in background that we don't see, when we just do ./foo ?

Kind of. What happens is that the kernel

1. checks that `./foo` has execute permissions
2. `mmap`s the file according to the program headers (`readelf -Wl foo`) in it
3. notices that the file has `PT_INTERP` segment, reads its contents (usually `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on Linux `x86_64` systems)
4. `mmap`s the interpreter according to its own program headers
5. transfers control to the interpreter in user space. It is then up to the interpreter to finish loading any needed shared libraries and initialize them, and finally transfer control to `foo`s `_start`.

Because of this startup sequence, for a dynamically linked `./foo`, 10s of thousands of instructions execute before `_start`.

This is also how it's possible to have `./foo` executable, but for attempts to run it produce "No such file or directory". You can try this for yourself:

```
gcc main.c -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/foo/bar/baz
ls -l a.out
./a.out
```

> I can still execute it with: `/path/to/ld.so ./foo`

In this case, you are skipping a few steps from the "normal" execution path.

From the kernel perspective, `ld.so` is a statically linked binary, and it *is* executable, so the kernel is happy to `mmap` its segments and transfer control to it.

And `ld.so` itself recognizes that it's been invoked in "unusual" way with command line arguments, so it proceeds to perform additional mappings of `./foo`s segments (which would have already been performed by the kernel otherwise). In order to perform the mappings, `ld.so` just needs a file; it doesn't care about permissions on that file.

This mode of operation proved very useful for e.g. testing new versions of `ld.so` itself.

It also allows you to run a binary with missing interpreter (the `a.out` above): `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./a.out` would work when `./a.out` doesn't.